# Angular 7 reactive form patchValue to null after an initial FormGroup fails

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formgroups

I have a FormGroup where the initial data may or may not be null.  If it is null, the FormGroup will be built like:

```
this.dataForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    prop1: true,
    testGroup: this.formBuilder.group({
      data: null,
      check: { a: "a", b: "b"}
    })
});
```

If it is not null, it will be built like:

```
this.dataForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    prop1: true,
    testGroup: this.formBuilder.group({
      data: this.formBuilder.group({ x: 0, y: 1}),
      check: { a: "a", b: "b"}
    })
});
```

The problem comes if I try to set the value of `data` to null if it was not initially null.

I have set up a stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-reactive-form-validation-fkhtjj) to demonstrate the problem.  The error is:

> can't convert null to object

Basically, the question is: Once a property has been set up as a `FormGroup`, how do you set it to `null`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This: `data: this.formBuilder.group({ x: 0, y: 1}),` is defining another FormGroup. What does it mean to "set it to null"? You want to set `x` and `y` to null? Remove the FormGroup? I'm not sure what "set to null" means in the context of the FormGroup you are creating.

Assuming you mean to set the *value* of the FormControls in the FormGroup to null values, then this works:

```
changeToNull2() {
  console.log(this.dataForm2);
  console.log(this.dataForm2.get('testGroup').value);
  this.dataForm2.get('testGroup.data').patchValue({
    x: null,
    y: null
  });
}
```

If you mean to remove the FormGroup defined by `data`, you can use `removeControl()` like this:

```
  (<FormGroup>this.dataForm2.get('testGroup')).removeControl('data');
```

Updated stackblitz that shows both: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-reactive-form-validation-aeshez

**UPDATE**

Just to clarify, in this code:

```
this.dataForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    prop1: true,
    testGroup: this.formBuilder.group({
      data: null,
      check: { a: "a", b: "b"}
    })
});
```

`data` is a FormControl whose value is defaulting to null.

In this code:

```
this.dataForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    prop1: true,
    testGroup: this.formBuilder.group({
      data: this.formBuilder.group({ x: 0, y: 1}),
      check: { a: "a", b: "b"}
    })
});
```

`data` is a FormGroup with two FormControls: `x` with a default value of 0 and `y` with a default value of 1.

Comment: Yes, thank you for the clarification. I meant that I want the value of the FormControl for data to be null.  The key was to first use `removeControl` as you suggested.  Immediately after that, I then added `(<FormGroup>this.dataForm2.get('testGroup')).addControl('data', new FormControl(null));`.  This adds back `data` as a FormControl with the value set to null.  Thanks!